# What determines the maximum number of bytes receivable with the recv() function of paramiko?

Tags: python, paramiko, recv

I was wondering how the `recv()` Funktion of paramiko actually works.

http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.13/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.recv

I noticed it has been discussed before how to receive more than the specified amount of data in bytes and how to use it ([How does paramiko Channel.recv() exactly work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125182/how-does-paramiko-channel-recv-exactly-work)).

However, I am wondering what determines the maximum number of bytes receivable by the `recv()` funtion. Is the `recv()` function analogue to the `recv()` function of the Python socket module? Is the maximum number of bytes determined by the maximum segment size (MSS) of the socket? Or by the MTU?